# How can I resolve this Loop problem in kotlin?

Tags: list, loops, android-studio, kotlin, range

I was watching an old programming tutorial about loops and ranges in Kotlin and I tried to copy that same code but apparently my Kotlin version did not respond well.

The original Source Code was:

```kotlin
val capitals= listOf("London", "Paris", "Rome", "Madrid")

for(capital in capitals){
  println(capital)
}
```

I have 2 Questions: First, why use capital and capitals again?

Also when I introduce the source code kotlin adds these symbols `<>`.

Updated Kotlin code (The one code causing me concern):

```kotlin
val capitals = listOf<> // (this is normal the problem is <>)
```

When I add the `listOf` to the value this automatically shows up.

Also, I don't know why the `for(capital in capitals) {...}` fails.

Comment: What do you mean by use them again? If you're wondering about `<>`, search the documentation for the page on *generics*.

Comment: uhh where is that ?

Comment: also I am new coding sry if I am annoying.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html But looking at that documentation, I see that it's written as if you're already very familiar with Java generics. You can read about that here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html Java syntax is a little bit different, but the basic concept is the same.

Comment: Generic specifies the type of the list, the content of the list. For example: string, integer or even own classes like car or customer. In your case the content of the list is string: listOf<String>("London", "Paris", "Rome", "Madrid")

Comment: Kotlin itself can guess the contents. Therefore you can also omit the type in your example. Technical term: type inference.

Comment: Alright after a thoroughly examination I realize that val capitals = listOf"London", "Paris", "Rome", "Madrid" is okay the problem comes when I try to apply for(capitals if capital)  that when I  try to println kotlin does not recognize the value capital but capitals it does.

Comment: it must be: for (item in list) .... in your example: for(capital in capitals){
  println(capital)
}

Comment: Kotlin Playground https://pl.kotl.in/zSM2xoeA1 - good luck.

Comment: @Twistleton OMG thank you :D is there a way that I can give you a like, follow or something similar? IDK a lot about stack overflow still. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @AlexionDark Glad to be able to help you. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided works as expected:

```
val capitals = listOf("London", "Paris", "Rome", "Madrid")

for(capital in capitals){
    println(capital)
}
```

Prints:

```
London
Paris
Rome
Madrid
```

> why use capital and capitals again?

Using `capital` variable in the [`for` loop](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#for-loops) you store each value of `capitals` list by iterating through it to handle it as you want.

When you declare a list like this `val capitals = listOf("London", "Paris", "Rome", "Madrid")`, it implies that you want to access its elements later. You can access its elements only by its name `capitals`, which you do in the for loop.

As for [generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html), classes or interfaces in Kotlin can have type parameters, which defined in `<>` brackets. [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/) is one of such classes.
If the generic parameters can be inferred, for example you can omit the type arguments and `<>` brackets.